# How Tensorflow text prediction predicts without softmax activation

Tags: tensorflow, rnn

In the Colab notebook here:  [RNN text generation](https://www.tensorflow.org/alpha/tutorials/text/text_generation)
in `def generate_text()`, there is 
`predicted_id = tf.random.categorical(predictions, num_samples=1)[-1,0].numpy()`

I looked into `tf.random.categorical` here:
[stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55063120/can-anyone-give-a-tiny-example-to-explain-the-params-of-tf-random-categorical)

and sort of understand how it works.

I tried to debug/figure out what it does with print statements:

```
for i in range(num_generate):
      predictions = model(input_eval)
      # remove the batch dimension
      predictions = tf.squeeze(predictions, 0)

      # using a categorical distribution to predict the word returned by the model
      predictions = predictions / temperature
      predicted_id1 = tf.random.categorical(predictions, num_samples=1)
      predicted_id2 = tf.random.categorical(predictions, num_samples=1)[-1,0]
      predicted_id3 = tf.random.categorical(predictions, num_samples=1)[0,0]
      predicted_id4 = tf.random.categorical(predictions, num_samples=1)[-2,0]
      predicted_id5 = tf.random.categorical(predictions, num_samples=1)[1,0]
      predicted_id6 = tf.random.categorical(predictions, num_samples=1)[2,0]
      predicted_id7 = tf.random.categorical(predictions, num_samples=1)[3,0]
      #predicted_id8 = tf.random.categorical(predictions, num_samples=1)[4,0]

      predicted_id = tf.random.categorical(predictions, num_samples=1)[-1,0].numpy() #index 0 for  

      print("predicted_id1", predicted_id1)
      print("predicted_id2", predicted_id2)
      print("predicted_id3", predicted_id3)
      print("predicted_id4", predicted_id4)
      print("predicted_id5", predicted_id5)
      print("predicted_id6", predicted_id6)
      print("predicted_id7", predicted_id7)

      print("predicted_id", predicted_id)
```

This was the output:

```
predicted_id1 tf.Tensor(
[[19]
 [33]
 [ 3]
 [35]
 [ 4]
 [64]
 [22]], shape=(7, 1), dtype=int64)
predicted_id2 tf.Tensor(35, shape=(), dtype=int64)
predicted_id3 tf.Tensor(19, shape=(), dtype=int64)
predicted_id4 tf.Tensor(3, shape=(), dtype=int64)
predicted_id5 tf.Tensor(38, shape=(), dtype=int64)
predicted_id6 tf.Tensor(26, shape=(), dtype=int64)
predicted_id7 tf.Tensor(36, shape=(), dtype=int64)
predicted_id 29
```

So it looks like there is some kind of distribution and that some of the indices pick from that distribution but the actual prediction in this case of `29` does not appear in the distribution so I am confused.  Are the elements in the distribution not integer ID's of characters in the text?  The one way I learned in the Udacity DLND was to assign probabilities to the predicted next character and choose the `argmax` so please feel free to enlighten me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logits have the distribution according to the len of vocabulary and the model training. So, you can use np.argmax(logits) to get the prediction, but normally to the application of generating script is more interesting to take into account a factor of aleatory which in this case is the function "random_categorical" which is used to get the value according to the probability. The value 29 appears in the distribution, you didn't see, because you execute the function a lot of times and every execution, "random values" will appear. If you want the exact value, use np.argmax.